# console.log() an object stripped of selected keys

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
let obj= {
   'Cow' : 'Moo',
   'Cat' : 'Meow',
   'Dog' : 'Bark'
};
```

I want to `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj_without_Cow))`, so this would be logged:

```
{
   'Cat' : 'Meow',
   'Dog' : 'Bark'
}
```

I could `delete` Cow, *destructure with rest*, or use several other approaches, but I was wondering if there is a way to only modify what is passed to console.log, as shown above. That is, without extra code outside of `console.log()`.

Analogically, if I was logging a `str = 'xxxyyy'`, I could have all 'x's removed: `console.log(str.replaceAll('x',''))`, it is intuitive to try `console.log(delete obj.Cow)` which, however, return true or false, not the modified object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without extra code outside of `console.log()`.

An IIFE does wonders for one-liners:

```
console.log( (({Cow, ...withoutCow}) => JSON.stringify(withoutCow))(obj) );
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`replacer` parameter to `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => key == 'Cow' ? undefined : val));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Underscore.js` or `Lodash`, there is a function 'omit' that will do it.
https://lodash.com/docs#omit

```js
const thisIsObject= {
    'Cow' : 'Moo',
    'Cat' : 'Meow',
    'Dog' : 'Bark'
};

console.log(_.omit(thisIsObject,'Cow'));

=> {'Cat' : 'Meow', 'Dog' : 'Bark'}
```

Or you can create your own `omit` function from pure JavaScript.

```js
const omit = (inputObject, removedKeys) =>
  Object.keys(inputObject)
    .filter((key) => !removedKeys.includes(key))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = inputObject[key];
      return obj;
    }, {});


console.log(omit(thisIsObject,'Cow'));

=> {'Cat' : 'Meow', 'Dog' : 'Bark'}
```